# Find mean of a group of every 10 layers in raster stack in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster stack (`s1`) of 2000 layers and I need to get mew stack of 20 layers from this (`s2`). Such that first layer in `s2` is mean of first 10 layers of `s1` and second `s2` layer is mean of 11-20 layers of `s1` and so on. I need to do this in R. I can use `calc` but I am confused what function would be like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a function that computes the means in each group. One way is to use `tapply` with a vector that looks like `[1,1,1,...1,1,2,2,2,...2,2,2......,20,20,20,20]`. Write a function to construct that vector and test:

```
> groupn=function(n,m){rep(1:m,rep(n/m,m))}
> groupn(20,2)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
> groupn(20,5)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

So there's two vectors that break 1 to 20 into 2 or 5 groups.

For testing I've created a raster stack of 20 layers which I want to compute means for every four layers, so corresponding to the second example above. First write a function to compute means by that group:

```
> group5 = groupn(20,5)
> group5
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
> f = function(v){tapply(v,group5,mean)}
```

I can now test `f` on any vector of length 20:

```
> f(1:20)
   1    2    3    4    5 
 2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5 18.5
```

which looks good - the mean of 1 to 5 is 2.5, the mean of 16 to 20 is 18.5 and so on.

Now put that in `calc`:

```
> out = calc(mystack, f)
> out
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 3, 4, 12, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 
min values  :  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 
max values  : 12, 12, 12, 12, 12
```

I should now check that the values in my little example are correct before going on to running it on a 2000 layer example...

Answer (score 4):

I have found how to do this. I am posting the answer so that it can help others.

```
indices<-rep(1:20,each=10)
s.mean<-stackApply(s, indices, fun = mean)
```

The answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798389/sum-nlayers-of-a-rasterstack-in-r

Comment: Sometimes its quicker for me to write something than look up the function that does it in one.... ;)